# How to hide dragText when using 'gridviewdragdrop' plugin in Extjs4.x?

Tags: extjs4

When using the 'gridviewdragdrop' plugin to implement drag and drop reorder function for a grid panel, while draging a record, a message with a icon(i.e, '1 selected row') displayed. I wonder if there is a way to hide this message? I tried to override the plugin but faied. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say what you tried...

In the definition, override the dragText:

```
plugins: {
    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
    dragText: ''
}
```